# How to Map Multiple Point to Destination Via Road Network and Represent Proportianally

Tags: qgis-processing

So I've been searching a lot and have found bits of information but no way to doing it from start to finish.

I have the following info:
.csv data of all the locations (Name,ID,latitude and longitude) (800 locations)
.csv data for the journeys taken from each location to another location (Millions of journeys)
Integrated Transport Network Map which has all road networks on it.

I would like to map every journey from each different point to another point via the road network. The goal is to represent areas of high usage as many of these points would overlap on the road network. I would then like to represent it proportionally so the map isn't too chaotic and shows areas on the road network with high and low usage represented by thickness of lines/colour.

I have read something about SQL and there is a Network Analyst tool on ArcMap. However all of theses seem to be on a small scale.